# DisplayTag convert timestamp into date

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, displaytag

I don't know if there is a question like this but I didn't find what I was looking for.
This is the problem:

In my database I have a table that has a value (**String**) of a timestamp. (i.e. **1370842140205**)

When I get that value in my `<display:table>` it shows exactly like that 1370842140205.

What I want is this: **10.6.2013 5.29.00**

How can i convert that String into desired date format in my .jsp file?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use this:

```
<display:table  name="${row.rows}">
    <display:column property="date" title="DATE" format="{0,date,MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss}"/>
</display:table>
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by my own. I modified the Select query. I used this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date` / 1000.0 ) ,  '%Y.%m.%d %k.%i.%s' ) as 'date' FROM table
```

Then I displayed it in my table as this:

```
<display:table  name="${row.rows}">
    <display:column property="date" title="DATE"/>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
long timeStamp = 1370842140205L;
Date time = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
String yourDate = time.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    long time=Long.parseLong("1370842140205");
    Date date = new Date(time);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh.mm.ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a column decorator to change your date and time format

```
    import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;
    import org.displaytag.decorator.DisplaytagColumnDecorator;
    import org.displaytag.exception.DecoratorException;
    import org.displaytag.properties.MediaTypeEnum;

    public class DateTimeDisplayColumnDecorator implements
    DisplaytagColumnDecorator {

@Override
public Object decorate(Object arg0, PageContext arg1, MediaTypeEnum arg2)
        throws DecoratorException {
    // Do your date conbersion code here
}

}
```

And in jsp add the decorator class name in decorator property

```
<display:column property="date" title="DATE"
 decorator="DateTimeDisplayColumnDecorator"/>
```